# Не работает поиск в Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, администрирование

Хотел переименовать пользователя в Windows 10, в связи с чем полез в редактор реестра. Там я изменил путь до пользователя, попытался переименовать его, но кнопка "переименовать" так и не появилась, вернул путь обратно

Но теперь возникла другая проблема - не работает поиск
Кликаю на "введите здесь текст для поиска" и ничего не происходит.

В чем может быть проблема?
Стоит отметить, что под другими пользователями все работает нормально, открывается

Comment: *В чем может быть проблема?* В том что Вы вместо штатного переименования полезли руками куда не надо, да ещё плохо понимая, что именно делаете. Попробуйте откатить всё, что натворили. Не получится - сохраняйте профиль и пересоздавайте пользователя.

Comment: @Akina да обычное штатное переименование не работало, нет кнопки "переименовать" у папки. Переименование пользователя не влияет на это. Помогла перезагрузка с обновлением

Comment: Штатно - создают нового пользователя, а потом указывают местоположение его профиля. От старого профиль отрывают, и его удаляют.

Comment: @Akina А можете дать линк с инструкцией? А то вот так в трех словах я явно где-то ошибусь)